# Where is the paper "Theorie de Lie pour les groupoides differentielles (J. Pradines)"?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Can anyone help me finding the paper:

"Theorie de Lie pour les groupoides differentielles (J. Pradines)"

I'm researching Lie groupoids and I was refered to that paper several times but couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: What results are attributed to that paper? I'm sure it would be in one or other of Mackenzies' two books on Lie groupoids. Otherwise there are more recent papers on Lie's theorems as far as they apply to Lie groupoids, if that is what it is referring to.

Comment: I agree Mackenzies' books must contain what I'm looking for, but it is always nice to check the original ideas.

Answer (score 4):

There is perhaps a longer article somewhere, but there are two short notes in Comptes Rendus.

```
@article {MR0216409,
    AUTHOR = {Pradines, Jean},
     TITLE = {Th\'eorie de {L}ie pour les groupo\"\i des diff\'erentiables.
              {C}alcul diff\'erenetiel dans la cat\'egorie des groupo\"\i
              des infinit\'esimaux},
   JOURNAL = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S\'er. A-B},
    VOLUME = {264},
      YEAR = {1967},
     PAGES = {A245--A248},
   MRCLASS = {53.42},
  MRNUMBER = {0216409 (35 \#7242)},
MRREVIEWER = {K.-T. Chen},
}

@article {MR0214103,
    AUTHOR = {Pradines, Jean},
     TITLE = {Th\'eorie de {L}ie pour les groupo\"\i des diff\'erentiables.
              {R}elations entre propri\'et\'es locales et globales},
   JOURNAL = {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris S\'er. A-B},
    VOLUME = {263},
      YEAR = {1966},
     PAGES = {A907--A910},
   MRCLASS = {57.70},
  MRNUMBER = {0214103 (35 \#4954)},
MRREVIEWER = {H. H. Johnson},
}
```

Comment: Should be available here: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb34416987n/date

Comment: Or directly: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6248451z/f49.image (1966 article), http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6435215p/f259.image (1967 article)